# I am gettin a MySQL syntax error in select query on visual studio 

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

This is my code, I think my query is wrong.

First of all `dataTimePicker1` info is being saved to database as string so that's why I tried converting `dateTimePicker1` to `.text`

```
private void consultarVta()
        {
            cn.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE fecha ="+dateTimePicker1.Text;
            MySqlDataAdapter daVentas = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, cn);
            DataSet dsVentas = new DataSet();
            daVentas.Fill(dsVentas, "ventas");
            dGvVentas.DataSource = dsVentas;
            dGvVentas.DataMember = "ventas";

            cn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: It's hard to know what's wrong with your SQL when you don't post the entire completed sql string that you execute. Can you please find out what the final sql string is after you modify it?

Comment: I'm assuming the dateTimePicker1 value is not surrounded by quotes. Try putting single quotes around the value and give it a go. Guess you'll need to do this by concatenation.

Comment: @Jebego that's my sql string and Brandon Jernigan I've tried single quotes but I still got the same error. BTW I don't have connection problems, VS says it's a syntax error. Thank you guys :)

Comment: @BrandonJernigan when I use single quotes I don't get any errors but it doesn't show me the information either. Thanks!

Comment: What's your full SQL string? "SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE fecha ="+dateTimePicker1.Text is not full. There is still a variable there. All I'm looking for is the final completed string once it has been added to and modified.

Comment: @Jebego that's all I got, is there something else I'm missing?? I want to get the info from ventas where fecha(date) is the same as the datimepicker. That's my full SQL string, I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## Update

Take a look at this answer: [Using variables in SQL queries in asp.net (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853660/using-variables-in-sql-queries-in-asp-net-c)

Comment: +1 .. while really "a comment", I feel the (answer in the linked post) is also "the solution". Consider expanding on how different input could cause syntax errors (or vulnerabilities), etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I needed and Thank you Brandond Jerningan that link really solved my problem all I had to do is:

```
string cmdText = "Select * from " + searchTable + " WHERE Name = '" +   searchValue + "'";
```