# Models and changing database schemas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can I still use the Entity Framework to access data in the database if my schema changes using asp.net mvc 5? For example, I have a customer model that has a name and id. If I add another column to the table that the customer model is modeled after, will it break my application if I don't update the model?

Another question is can I perform queries without knowing about the exact column names or even the schema? For example, I only have the Database name and Tables the user wants to query given from user input on the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't start the data layer using code first or made changes to the database model directly, then you will want to reverse engineer it. The details are at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx.

This would be probably the best way to synchronize the database back into your model if using EF.  Otherwise, you would need to write your own ADO.NET code or use another ORM framework that might give you more leniency.

Comment: Thanks. I found what I was looking for over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853660/using-variables-in-sql-queries-in-asp-net-c

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is absolutely, positively, maybe it will break your application. If you use that model to insert data into the database and the newly added column does not allow nulls then anywhere that you insert data will break. If you strictly use it for querying it should be fine.

I don't really understand the second question. How would you query the database if you don't know the schema or column names? What would you do with the results? Perhaps you could update your question with an example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: If I only knew the Database name and tables (from user input), I'd be able to simply display the results of the query on the web page. That is why I am wondering if I need the data as a model to display it on the page, similar to Rails.

Comment: So you're building a query tool that your users can use to execute commands against your database? That seems like a bad idea but I don't know the whole story so maybe you've got safeguards in place to prevent malicious queries (at least I hope so).

Comment: I have safeguards in place (selecting from dropdownlist with parameterized queries). Thanks for your help.